# CTE with ROW_NUMBER() within recursive UNION ALL part

Tags: recursion, common-table-expression, row-number

I try to get a bill explosion.
I already get the first level ("Ebene1") by using Row_Number()... as rn and filter that to rn = 1. I need that because there are more than one versions of one material number available.

In the recursive CTE part (UNION ALL), I have the problem, that it shows the ROW_NUMBER() rn2 but my problem is, that after each iteration (e.g. column Ebene = 2 or 3 or ..) there should be just the first rows added to the cte before next iteration/recursion starts. Unfortunately it uses all rows for next iterations. Because of that I get materials which are not correct. All materials which have the value "1" in column rn2 are the ones, which are correct.
If I filter outside of the cte (so at the end of my code I do " rn2 = '1' ") it just filters out all the rows AFTER all iterations. That means I have rows in my final table which I do not want.
Reason: Because I join t1.material = cte.submaterial and if within the recursion I also get e.g. rn2=2 than it will do that join and I get in the next iteration for that new row rn2=1 and therefore I get that material in my final table.

So what I need is a filter for rn2 **within** the UNION ALL part, **before** it will be added to the cte-table.

Is this possible?

Here is my code (I simplified it a little bit):

```
WITH First_Step AS (
SELECT
    partlist,
    material as Material_Ebene1,
    material as Material,
    costcenter,
    submaterial,
    quantity,
    description,
    1 AS Ebene,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY plant||partlistID||partlist||material||costcenter||submaterial||position ORDER BY adate||bdate||version DESC) AS rn

    FROM mat_bom

    LEFT JOIN material
    ON mat_bom.material = material.material
    AND mat_bom.plant = material.plant

    LEFT JOIN bom_header
    ON mat_bom.partlist = bom_header.partlist
    AND mat_bom.plant = bom_header.wrkan

    LEFT JOIN bom_item
    ON mat_bom.partlist = bom_item.partlist

    LEFT JOIN mat_description
    ON bom_item.submaterial = mat_description.material

    WHERE
    mat_bom.plant = '0815'

),
Ebene1 AS (
    SELECT
    First_Step.partlist, First_Step.mat, First_Step.material, First_Step.costcenter, First_Step.submaterial, First_Step.quantity, First_Step.description, First_Step.Ebene, First_Step.rn
    from First_Step
    where
    rn = '1'
),
cte(partlist, mat, material, costcenter, submaterial, quantity, description, Ebene, rn2) AS (
SELECT Ebene1.partlist, Ebene1.mat, Ebene1.material, Ebene1.costcenter, Ebene1.submaterial, Ebene1.quantity, Ebene1.description, Ebene1.Ebene, Ebene1.rn
FROM Ebene1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
    t1.partlist,
    cte.mat,
    t1.material,
    cte.costcenter,
    t3.submaterial,
    t3.quantity,
    t4.description,
    Ebene + 1 AS Ebene,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.partlist||t3.position||cte.costcenter ORDER BY t3.datuv||t3.node DESC) AS rn2

    FROM mat_bom t1

    LEFT JOIN bom_header t5
    ON t1.partlist = t5.partlist
    AND t1.plant = t5.wrkan
  
    LEFT JOIN bom_item t3
    ON t1.partlist = t3.partlist
  
    LEFT JOIN mat_description t4
    ON t3.submaterial = t4.material

    JOIN cte
    ON t1.material = cte.submaterial

    WHERE
    t1.plant = '0815'

)
SELECT cte.partlist, cte.mat, cte.material, cte.costcenter, cte.submaterial, cte.quantity, cte.description, cte.Ebene, cte.rn2
FROM cte
WHERE
rn2 = '1'
```

Hope, someone can help on that. I really looked a lot for that problem, but I could not find any solution.

An example, which hopefully makes it clear:

[image]